# R Datatable Styling one Column Based on Another Column and Hiding Column Does Not Work after Running Shiny App

Tags: r, dt

I'm trying to follow the example on the R DT [website](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/010-style.html) to style one column based on another column and hide the column that I use for styling but the column was not hidden (it works fine if I run it in a new R session but does not work if I run it after I run my Shiny app). My code is as follow:

```
library(DT)
df = as.data.frame(cbind(matrix(round(rnorm(50), 3), 10),
                         sample(0:1, 10, TRUE)))

datatable(df, options = list(columnDefs = list(list(targets = 6,
                                               visible = FALSE)))) %>%
    formatStyle('V1', 'V6', backgroundColor = styleEqual(c(0, 1),
                                                         c('gray', 'yellow')))
```

Column `V6` is supposed to be hidden but as you can see from this picture, it is still visible:
[image]

Session info is as follow:

```
R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21)
Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7.4 (Maipo)

Matrix products: default
BLAS/LAPACK: /usr/lib64/R/lib/libRblas.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8   
 [6] LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] bindrcpp_0.2.2     webshot_0.4.1      stringr_1.3.1      shinythemes_1.1.1  shinyjs_1.0        plotly_4.7.1       ggplot2_3.0.0.9000 lubridate_1.7.4   
 [9] DT_0.4.17          dplyr_0.7.6        data.table_1.11.4  AGD_0.39           shiny_1.1.0       

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] tidyselect_0.2.4   reshape2_1.4.3     purrr_0.2.2.2      splines_3.4.0      lattice_0.20-35    colorspace_1.3-2   htmltools_0.3.6    viridisLite_0.3.0 
 [9] yaml_2.1.19        survival_2.41-3    rlang_0.2.1        later_0.7.3        pillar_1.3.0       glue_1.3.0         withr_2.1.2        RColorBrewer_1.1-2
[17] bindr_0.1.1        plyr_1.8.4         munsell_0.5.0      gtable_0.2.0       devtools_1.13.3    htmlwidgets_1.2.1  memoise_1.1.0      gamlss.dist_5.0-2 
[25] crosstalk_1.0.0    httpuv_1.4.4.1     gamlss_5.0-2       gamlss.data_5.0-0  curl_2.8.1         parallel_3.4.0     Rcpp_0.12.17       xtable_1.8-2      
[33] promises_1.0.1     scales_0.5.0       jsonlite_1.5       mime_0.5           digest_0.6.15      stringi_1.2.3      grid_3.4.0         tools_3.4.0       
[41] magrittr_1.5       lazyeval_0.2.1     tibble_1.4.2       crayon_1.3.4       tidyr_0.6.3        pkgconfig_2.0.1    MASS_7.3-47        Matrix_1.2-9      
[49] assertthat_0.2.0   httr_1.2.1         rstudioapi_0.6     R6_2.2.2           git2r_0.19.0       nlme_3.1-131       compiler_3.4.0
```

Anyone has any idea why it's not working as expected?

Comment: It works fine for me. Have you tried this in a new R session?

Comment: Hmm this works if I start a new R session. However, if I run it after I run a Shiny app that I'm working on, the columns are not hidden. I'll need to figure out if my Shiny app is messing things up.

Comment: Interesting . . . You should edit your question to highlight that fact